# JavaScript: Manipulate matrix row at index

Tags: javascript, matrix, in-place

I am trying to solve this problem:

I seem to get everything EXCEPT: manipulating the row of a matrix at a specific index. The code that I wrote, performs the function at all of the rows, not the specified row.

Here is the code:

```
const solvematrix= (r, c, indices) => {
    let matrix = new Array(r).fill(new Array(c).fill(0));

    for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        // get index values to increase
        let rIdx = indices[i][0];
        let cIdx = indices[i][1];

        // modify row matrix in-place ; This is where the Error is
        matrix[rIdx].map((cv, idx, array) => array[idx]++);

        // modify column matrix in-place
        matrix[cIdx].map((cv, idx, array) => (cIdx === idx ? array[idx]++ : null));
    }

    return matrix;
};


solvematrix(2, 3, [[0, 1],[1, 1]])
Output: [[2,4,2],[2,4,2]]
Expected: [[1,3,1],[1,3,1]]
```

As you can in the output above, the values are increased for all the numbers in rows, not just the specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this on repl, and I get the expected output. The only error I get is when calling `oddCells`. You are missing a closing parenthesis there. Just update it to `oddCells(2, 3, [[0, 1], [1, 1]])`.

Although I can't say I fully understand the problem you are trying to solve. Base on your description, the expected output even seems wrong to me. Shouldn't we only be incrementing values at each specific indices pair? If that was the case, for this example, wouldn't the output look like:

```
[[0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0]]
```

***** Edit *****

Thanks for clarifying. So I took another look, this was a tricky one. A couple of things.

1. There are some issues when creating arrays with `new Array`. The issue that affected us was that it seems to only create a single object, with a single reference. So even though you were creating several rows within your matrix, all those rows where actually the same underlying object. If you console logged the rows, you would see that after the first iteration, we updated the second row as well. This site was useful to kind of get a sense of things: https://2ality.com/2018/12/creating-arrays.html. This was the tricky part!

So the first fix is to change that, and instead use `Array.from` which creates a brand new array every time.

2. The second issue you were having was when updating the columns. There you were trying to iterate over `matrix[cIdx]`, which could be any row. This does not pull out the column you want to update. To update the specific column you would have to do something like

`matrix[rowIdx][colIdx] = somevalue`

Here is a re-write:

```
const oddCells = (r, c, indices) => {
    let matrix = Array.from({length: r}, () => Array.from({length: c}, () => 0));
    for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        // get index values to increase
        let rIdx = indices[i][0];
        let cIdx = indices[i][1];
        // update rows
        matrix[rIdx] = matrix[rIdx].map(v => v++); 
        // update columns
        matrix.forEach((row, idx) => row[cIdx]++);
    }

    return matrix;
};


oddCells(2, 3, [[0, 1],[1, 1]]);
```

Also, as an aside. The way that you were using `.map` is a bit of an anti-pattern. Usually if you want to mutate something directly you can use `.forEach`. `.map` returns a new array every time with the update values. So typically you can just set the value to that new array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did make a mistake when copying the problem here. Putting that aside, I think you misunderstood the problem. Each indices represent index of a matrix [Row index, Colum index] and my goal is to increase the numbers at a given row or column. So  for ex, [0,1] would increase row 0 by one then increase column 1 by one.

Comment: wow thank you! I did notice that my matrix was updating the 2nd row as well, but I couldn't understand why it was doing that. Thank you for the tip for the difference between .forEach and .map methods. Learned many new things today. I really appreciate your help!